# Why there are no good open-source development tools? Shouldn't it be a priority for the community?

Tags: c++, open-source, ide

My native language is not english, so please sorry my mistakes.

I'm doing a course of free technologies and recently I've been learning Linux and it seems promising, however, I couldn't find good development tools, something like Visual Studio.
After trying a lot of other IDEs, none of them gets close to MSVS functionality.

I know it's not easy to develop a good IDE, but there are dozens of "almost-there" IDEs, I wonder what they could do if the developers had joined efforts.

Also, I'm just wondering... Why the open-source community doesn't have a good IDE on top of the priority list.

After researching a little, I found a lot of articles describing how the OS community works, they always break apart, when things are getting usable they just dissipate and begin to work on more unusable things.

This made me very sad, because I thought open-source were serious stuff, and that's why I choose the course on free technologies, now I'm almost decided to give up.

There are hundreds of Linux distros, and hundreds of similar software that does almost the same thing, from desktop environments to python scripts, people are reinventing the wheel. Open-source is quantity and not quality.

If I can't find a good C++ IDE that has the features I'm used to, I'm going to give up. I'm not a genius geek, just a normal or maybe dumb guy who programs in C++ and is used to tools that facilitate the development. Emacs, Vim, all that stuff is too much for me. If that were the only tools available for programming, then programmers would be the rarest persons in the world because you need to be a super-genius to use these tools.

The features I want in a C++ IDE are:
-Good code highlighting
-Pop-up documentation
-Good debugger with visual aid
-Usable and smart code completion

Thank you.

Comment: You know, this depends on the taste. For me emacs is the greatest IDE. Others may want something similar to MSVC. You may have not searched enough, because if you look at Eclipse + CDT, you get all (and much more) from MSVC. Also, Netbeans has great C++ support, etc (Kdevelop, QtCreator, Code::Blocks, etc etc.)

Comment: No other OS has a filesystem like Windows, or a window system like Windows, or a file manager quite like Windows, or an email client like Windows, or anything else.  If your definition of "good" is "like I'm used to", everything is going to look bad to you.

Comment: By the way, most folks coming from the other side wonder why there's no working C compiler/runtime for Windows...

Comment: There are several open-source IDEs out there with code highlighting, pop-up documentation, visual debugging, and code completion. As others have stated, the most prominent are Eclipse and Netbeans, both of which have rather mature c++ support. You need to be more specific in stating why the available alternatives don't meet your requirements; just saying that their implementation of these features isn't "good" is almost flamebait.

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry if my question sounds flame or something. Basically, I refuse to program without these 3 features: 1-Any kind of pop-up documentation, 2-Visual aid for debugging, 3-Capable code completion, like intellisense. So, is there any IDE that has these features, I've tried QT-Creator and the code completion is impressive but not close to intellisense. It fails to detect complex pieces of code. Thank you.

Comment: @Alan Then you'll probably feel most at home in the MS world. That doesn't mean everybody else has the same priorities and prefers hand-holding to such a degree as VS provides. Some people prefer Assembler, for crying out loud! :o) To each his own.

Comment: Even after 20+ years of being spoiled by fancy IDEs I can still be pretty darn productive with little more than vi and a compiler.  I would almost recommend vi or emacs for efficiency.  Once you know the commands you can do anything you need to without picking up the mouse.  Terminal editors are *very* powerful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're encountering is a difference in culture. Surely there would not be the amount of free and open source software that exists if nobody had the tools to develop it. But the people who are developing it are mostly used to a very different flavor of tools that what folks brought up on Visual Basic are used to. Emacs, ctags, make, gdb, strace, ltrace, and so on are all very powerful and much more natural to somebody used to unix than a MS-style IDE... and I hesitate to simply say IDE, because many FOSS developers consider emacs itself to be an "IDE".

Perhaps your question would be more productive and less inflammatory if you instead asked "Why are there no open source MSVS-like IDEs?"

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Diego Sevilla comment.

My first experience as developer was with Visual Studio and that skew my way of work.

Like my mind was trying to use something equals to Visual Studio, but that is only an habit.

After Visual Studio I moved to Eclipse, I loved it! at that times with visual studio and subversion you needed an external tool! (today exists some tools out there).

Now I am using vim, why? ultra fast, customizable and minimal (if you want).

But the best best example of open source IDE is smalltalk, I wish all programming lenguage came with the tools smalltalk provide.

Answer (score 0):

Um, get Eclipse or Netbeans.  Both are great free IDEs with millions of users.

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source IDE's. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments  You can see some of the licenses.